# How do I center 2 images in a circular div while also overlapping them?

Tags: html, css, centering

I've been messing with a bootstrap template...pretty standard row with 3 items.

Each of the row items I've turned into divs with a circular background.
Now, I'm trying to take 2 images (so I can animate them) and center them in the div.

I've found a few ways to hack around it...but I'm wondering what the best way to do this is?

I want to be able to control the layering & make sure they're vertically centered at all times.

Absolute positioning one of them borks the centering of the other right now...

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="feature-icon">
                <div id="phone">

                    <img class="behind" src="img/svg/phone.svg" width="40">
                    <img src="img/svg/pocket.svg" width="70">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
img.behind {
z-index: 0;
position: relative;
left: 20px;
top: 40px;
}
```

Here's what it looks like right now.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your current code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you really need to show some code.  What does your html look like?  css?  It all depends on that.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's my first Stack Overflow post.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really understand your question.  But for full control of a DIV within a container using absolute position is to make the parent container relative.

HTML

```
<div id="parent-container">
     <div id="animated-object1" class="object"></div>
     <div id="animated-object2" class="object"></div>
     <div id="animated-object3" class="object"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent-container{
   position:relative;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin: auto;
   width:100%;
   height:500px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.object{
   position: absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#animated-object1{
  left:300px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

JavaScript - jQuery - onclick- animation syntax

```
$('#parent-container').on('click', function(){
    $('#animated-object1').animate({
      left: "0px"
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lufvdfn/4/